# Unexpected behavior of Java ArrayList.set() method with multiplication in forEach loop

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, indexof

Setting initial array values (no issue):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class arraylists {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        numbers.add(3);
        numbers.add(1);
        numbers.add(4);
        numbers.add(2);
        System.out.println(numbers.toString());
    }
}
```

Console output: [3, 1, 4, 2]

Trying `forEach` addition (no issue):

```
numbers.forEach(number -> {
    numbers.set(numbers.indexOf(number), number + 10);
});
System.out.println(numbers.toString());
```

Console output: [13, 11, 14, 12]

Trying `forEach` multiplication:

```
numbers.forEach(number -> {
    numbers.set(numbers.indexOf(number), number * 2);
});
System.out.println(numbers.toString());
```

Console output: [6, **4**, 8, **2**]

My question is, why does the array after the multiplication loop have value 4 at index 1 and value 2 at index 3? Shouldn't they be 1 * 2 = 2 and 2 * 2 = 4, respectively?

I tried the above code and was expecting after the forEach multiplication to have an array with values [6, 2, 8, 4]. Instead I got [6, **4**, 8, **2**].

Comment: After the second element has been processed, what's the index of element with value 2?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry, I wasn't trying to unilaterally revoke your closure, I thought mine would only count as a vote to reopen.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Haha, it's good to have the hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the index of the first occurrence of a value. Let's walk through the loop and see what's going on.

1. We start with [3, 1, 4, 2]
2. The first element is 3. Its index is 0, so we get [6, 1, 4, 2]
3. The second element is 1. Its index is 1, so we get [6, 2, 4, 2]
4. The third element is 4. Its index is 2, so we get [6, 2, 8, 2]
5. The fourth element is 2. Its first index is 1, so we get [6, 4, 8, 2]

Not only is this wrong (as you've seen), it also means that for each iteration you need to search the entire list (with `indexOf`) for a value that you already should have known where it is.

Using a good old `for` loop would be better suited here:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
    numbers.set(i, numbers.get(i) * 2);
}
```

Comment: Or `map`, if they want to use streams.

Comment: Oh okay this makes sense to me now, I was confused about how that method worked in practice. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca true, but then you'll have to collect the stream into a new list instead of updating the current one. Could be OK in some (most?) cases, but I didn't want to assume that.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an incorrect result during multiplication because when the last element is being processed, the list looks like this `[6, 2, 8, 2]` (the element at index `1` has been changed to `2`). Therefore, `indexOf()` return `1`, not `3` (as you probabely expected).

In cases like this when you need to replace each element in the list, you can use Java 8 method [`List.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) which is far more convenient since you don't need to dial with indices:

```
numbers.replaceAll(number -> number * 2);

System.out.println(numbers);
```

*Output:*

```
[6, 2, 8, 4]
```